# Add another Update for Merge Into PL SQL trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge, triggers, upsert

I have to upsert table from another table.

Here is the table MST_LIST

```
NAME | VER | FLAG
-----+-----+-----
A    |201  |1
B    |101  |1
```

And TMP_LIST to update previous table

```
T_NAME | T_VER
-------+-------
A      |202
C      |101
```

And I used merge to upsert. This is the code that I created.

```
  create or replace TRIGGER MST_LIST_TRIG 
     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TMP_LIST
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     MERGE INTO MST_LIST USING DUAL ON ( NAME = :NEW.T_NAME )
     WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
       VER = :NEW.T_VER
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (NAME, VER, FLAG_ACTIVE)
         VALUES (:NEW.T_NAME, :NEW.T_VER, 1);
     END MST_LIST_TRIG;
```

But the problem is I need to add another update

```
    update MST_LIST set FLAG = 0 where NOT EXISTS
(SELECT TMP_LIST.T_NAME FROM TMP_LIST WHERE MST_LIST.NAME = TMP_LIST.T_NAME);
```

to get result like this

```
NAME | VER | FLAG
-----+-----+-----
A    |202  |1
B    |101  |0
C    |101  |1
```

I tried Loop and If but still can't get the excpected result. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a autonomous transaction in your trigger to achieve this. See below:

```
create or replace TRIGGER MST_LIST_TRIG 
     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TMP_LIST
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     MERGE INTO MST_LIST USING DUAL ON ( NAME = :NEW.T_NAME )
     WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
       VER = :NEW.T_VER
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (NAME, VER, FLAG_ACTIVE)
         VALUES (:NEW.T_NAME, :NEW.T_VER, 1);         

  --Calling a autonomous proc here 
   proc_upd();   
 END MST_LIST_TRIG;
```

Autonomous transaction:

```
create or replace  procedure proc_upd
as
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin

   UPDATE MST_LIST
   SET FLAG = 0
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT TMP_LIST.T_NAME
             FROM TMP_LIST
            WHERE MST_LIST.NAME = TMP_LIST.T_NAME);

    commit;

END;
```